# Decrypting Vernam Cipher

Tags: c

I'm creating a code for encryption and decryption for Vernam Cipher.

Initially, to encrypt a message, I would have to use a function that would generate my OTP. This function produces random numbers from 1-26 (to signify the english alphabet) and would be stored in an array of integers. The size is equal to the length of the message to be encrypted.

I was able to do that. My problem is how I would decrypt it.

I have this code.

**My OTP array, since each element is randomized between 1-26, would signify an nth letter of the alphabet. e.g. 25 would signify the letter 'y' and so on.**
The logic of my encryption is that since the size of my OTP array is equal to the length of my message, I would do XOR on each of the character of my message and my OTP. This is after converting my OTP array to corresponding letters of the alphabet depending on each element's randomized assigned number.
I was able to do the encryption part already. But whenever I try to decrypt, I get a different message from what I initially inputted.

```
void encryptiondecryption(char msg[], char key[]){
    
    int i,j=0,x,m=0;

    char output[100];
    char output2[100];

/* Loop to remove all spaces in the message here*/  

/*Encryption*/    
    int modd;
    for(x = 0; msg[x]!='\0'; x++) {
    printf("\nletter:%c - key:%c",msg[x], key[x] );
        modd = (msg[x] ^ key[x]);
        if(modd == 26){
            output[x] = 'a'+ (modd%26)+25;
        }else{
            output[x] = 'a'+ (modd%26)-1;
        }
    }
    output[x]='\0';

    printf("\nEncrypted Message:\n");
    for(x = 0; output[x]!='\0'; x++) {
        printf("%c",output[x]);
    }

/* decryption */

    int modd2,diff,sum, toXOR;
    printf("\n\ndecryption\n");

    for(x = 0; output[x]!='\0'; x++) {
        printf("\nletter:%c - key:%c",output[x], key[x] );
        diff = output[x] - 'a';
        if(diff == 25){
            sum = diff - 25;
            toXOR = sum + 26;
            output2[x] = toXOR ^ key[x];
        }else{
            sum = diff + 1;
            toXOR = sum + 26;
            output2[x] = toXOR ^ key[x];
        }

    }

    output2[x]='\0';
    printf("\n Output for Decryption\n");
        for(i = 0;  output2[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        printf("%c",output2[i]);
    }
}
```

In addition, this is my generateOTP function.

```
char* generateKey(char msg[]){
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    int len = strlen(msg);
    

    int numbers[len];
    int x,y=0, m=0,a;
    
    for(x=0;x<len;x++){
        if(msg[x]!='_') m++;
    }

    
    printf("generated key is . . .\n");
    int *getOTP = malloc (sizeof (int)*len);
    
    for(x=0;x<m;x++){
        getOTP[x] = rand() % (26 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    }
    for(x=0;x<m;x++){
        printf("%d ", getOTP[x]);
    }
    
    char *letterOTP = malloc (sizeof (char) * len);
    int getOTP2[m];
    for(x=0;x<m;x++){
        getOTP2[x] = getOTP[x];
    }

    int md;
    for(x=0;x<m;x++){
        md = (getOTP2[x]) % 26;
        if(md ==0){
            letterOTP[x] =( 97 + (md));
        }else{
            letterOTP[x] =( 97 + (md) - 1);
        }
        
    }
    letterOTP[x] = '\0';

    return letterOTP;
    
}
```

Basically, what this does as I have mentioned above, is that assigns a letter of an alphabet depending on what number an element in the array was randomly assigned to `(e.g. 25 = 'y', 5 = 'e')`

Comment: You apply a modulus 26 after you xor'ed the msg with the key. Wouldn't that make it loose information?

Comment: @Emanuel P That's what I thought too. For example I got 'c' after encryption and there would be multiple possibilities. Because before applying mod 26, I may have gotten 4 or 30 or so.

Comment: Yes, but that's I think exactly the problem. If 'c' for example would be 30, and 'z' would be 4, then after mod 26 they would both be 4. So you'd have no way to know what to decrypt a 4 to.

Comment: @rinrin I don't really understand why you are performing the `%26` during encryption. For Vernam cipher, one just needs to XOR the key with the encrypted output to decrypt it. That is all there is. Could you explain why the modulo operations?

Comment: @Zoso Im basing in our class discussion on how it was encrypted. I applied mod 26 so that I could display it in terms of alphabet letters

Comment: @rinrin In that case, keep a separate buffer (or just a simple for loop offsetting each character and printing it). You are going to cause problems modding _and_ storing it in the same buffer and later decrypting it.